# Problemas con el ROW_NUMBER() SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Saludos a la comunidad.

Tengo una consulta y duda con respecto a `ROW_NUMBER()`; para empezar, mi consulta es la siguiente:

```sql
DECLARE @TSaldoEmisionCliente TABLE(indice int, saldo numeric(12,2), emision datetime, cliente varchar(255)) 
INSERT INTO @TSaldoEmisionCliente 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.Cliente ORDER BY T.Cliente), T.SaldoSol, T.Emision,T.Cliente 
FROM @Tabla T 
WHERE T.OrdenDoc=1 AND (ISNULL(T.SaldoSol,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(T.SaldoDolar,0) <> 0)
```

La misma me trae como resultado lo siguiente:

| indice | saldo | emision | cliente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2021-09-07 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ CABANILLAS WILFREDO MANUEL |
| 2 | 41 | 2021-09-09 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ CABANILLAS WILFREDO MANUEL |
| 3 | 9 | 2021-09-10 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ CABANILLAS WILFREDO MANUEL |
| 1 | 102.8 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ GARCIA FREDDY ELISEO |
| 2 | 368.3 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ GARCIA FREDDY ELISEO |
| 3 | 10 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ GARCIA FREDDY ELISEO |

Y así sucesivamente... lo que en realidad quisiera que me resulte es algo como esto:

| indice | saldo | emision | cliente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2021-09-07 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ CABANILLAS WILFREDO MANUEL |
| 1 | 41 | 2021-09-09 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ CABANILLAS WILFREDO MANUEL |
| 1 | 9 | 2021-09-10 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ CABANILLAS WILFREDO MANUEL |
| 2 | 102.8 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ GARCIA FREDDY ELISEO |
| 2 | 368.3 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ GARCIA FREDDY ELISEO |
| 2 | 10 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.000 | DIAZ GARCIA FREDDY ELISEO |

Es decir, que en vez se me liste un índice diferente por cada registro del mismo cliente, se me liste el mismo índice para todos los registros de un solo cliente.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que reemplazar tu `ROW_NUMBER` por `DENSE_RANK`:

```
DECLARE @TSaldoEmisionCliente TABLE(indice int, saldo numeric(12,2), emision datetime, cliente varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @TSaldoEmisionCliente 
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY T.Cliente), 
    T.SaldoSol, 
    T.Emision,T.Cliente 
FROM @Tabla T 
WHERE T.OrdenDoc = 1 
AND (ISNULL(T.SaldoSol,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(T.SaldoDolar,0) <> 0) 
;
```

Comment: Elimino el `PARTITION BY` ? o no es un requerimiento para el `DENSE_RANK` ?

Comment: tienes que eliminar el `PARTITION BY` porque si no obtendrás los resultados erróneos que mostraste previamente. `PARTITION BY` es opcional para las funciones analíticas como `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, etc

Comment: Me resultó! una consulta más en el `ORDER BY` que está dentro del `OVER()` puedo colocar otro condición más para el orden como por ejemplo `T.Emision` o es mejor colocar otro `ORDEN BY`, pero luego del `WHERE`?, porque así como lo haz puesto me lista en desorden, no empieza por el índice 1.